# Is iTunes duplicating music files?

Tags: itunes, itunes-11

I recently discovered the way iTunes organized my music into iTunes > iTunes Media > Music folder, but these folders aren't where I originally imported the music from.

Is iTunes duplicating my .mp3 files, and putting them altogether in this folder, and keeping the original source where it is too? I like the idea, but it's using lots of space that I need!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can be set to, or set not to, in the preferences. Specifically there is a checkbox under "Advanced Preferences" for **Copy files to iTunes Media Folder when adding to library**. If checked, it copies.